# PL/SQL Using IN clause with a table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm using Oracle Apex 4.2 with database 11.g.  I need to compare a value received from a user (l_requested_time) with values stored in a table column (music_lookup.valid_time).  If the supplied value is contained in the table, then the transaction should proceed.  If the supplied value is not in the table, then the transaction should be cancelled.  I'm constructing this in SQL Developer before I put it in Apex.  When I execute the following code in SQL Developer I receive an error message: PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context.  I just don't know how to get around this restriction.

```
Declare
  l_requested_time varchar2(256);
Begin
  l_requested_time := '10:00 AM';
  If l_requested_time in (select valid_time from music_lookup)
  Then dbms_output.put_line('The transaction is authorized');
  Else dbms_output.put_line('The transaction is NOT authorized');
  End if;
End;
```

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

1. Your PL/SQL logic is syntactically wrong. You need to do something like

> ```
> Declare
>   l_requested_time varchar2(256);
>   junk varchar2(1);
> Begin
>   l_requested_time := '10:00 AM';
>   select 'x' into junk from music_lookup where requested_time = l_requested_time;
>   dbms_output.put_line('The transaction is authorized');
>
> exception
>   when no_data_found then
>     dbms_output.put_line('The transaction is NOT authorized');
> End;
> ```

Now, there is actually another condition that would raise an error; what if there was more than one row that me the condition? 
I suspect that there is more to query that just time; user_id for example?

2. You should really be using DATE (or TIMESTAMP) data types for dates/times.

Comment: Hi BobC,  Thanks for replying.  I really appreciate it.  That's a great approach and works fine.  To answer your other concerns:  1) The query shouldn't return more than one row since I have a Unique Key constraint on the music_lookup table based on the combination of the Requested_Time and UserName fields.  The combined key indicates that a user is authorized to edit any record with a timestamp containing that time of day.  2) The l_requested_time field is extracted from a Timestamp field.  I didn't include the UserName since I was using SQLDeveloper before I moved it to Apex.  Thanks again.